# CakePHP 3 create association between tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have got two tables in my database. The Jobs are meant to be used as a list of available jobs, which should be categorized in different business genres.

jobs

```
id(int) PRIMARY
title(varchar)
business_id(int)
start(datetime)
description(text)
```

business

```
id(int) PRIMARY
name(varchar)
```

In jobs index I would like to show a list of all Jobs and their categories. But I am getting stuck on receiving the business name from the jobs controller.

JobsTable.php

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class JobsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->HasOne('Business', ['foreignKey' => 'business_id']);
    }
}
```

BusinessTable.php

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class BusinessTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Jobs', ['foreignKey' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

JobsController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('jobs'));
    }
```

What do I have to do to use the business name from the business table inside my JobsController and its views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to prats1411 for his fast anwser.

I recently found a way to get it working for me. If somebody is able to provide a better solution, I would really recommend that.

in src/Model/Table/JobsTable.php:

```
$this->belongsTo('Business', ['foreignKey' => 'business_id']);
```

in src/Controller/JobsController.php:

```
$jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all')->contain('Business');
```

So i could finally show the Business name with `$job->busines->name` inside my view.

Answer (score 1):

In your view of Jobs, you can try something like this

```
foreach($jobs as $job) :

    echo $job->has('business') ? $this->Html->link($job->business->name, ['controller' => 'Businesses', 'action' => 'view', $job->business->id]) : ''

endforeach;
```

Comment: Seems to be always false. `$job->business->name` returns a `Trying to get property of non-object`Error.